# defined recursively

Tags: discrete-mathematics, recursion

Question: A sequence is defined recursively by

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
 a_{n+2} &=& 2a_{n+1} - a_n \\ a_0 &=& 2 \\ a_1 &=& 1 
\end{array}
\right.
$$

Find $a_4$
Anyone know how to do this?
This is what I've done I'm not sure if its correct.
$a_2 = 2a_2+1 - 2 = 1$

$ a_3 = 2a_3+1 - 3 = 1$

$ a_4 = 2a_4+1 - 4 = 4$

Comment: What do you mean by "doing this"? What's the difficulty that you're encountering, precisely? At least there is a mistake in your calculation:
$a_3 = 2\times 1 - 2 = 0$; $a_4 = 2\times 0 -1 = -1$ ... By calculating some terms, you probably start seeing a pattern emerging.

Answer (score 0):

Just do them one after another.

$a_{n+2} = 2a_{n+1} -a_n$.

So $a_2 = 2a_1  - a_0 = 2*1 - 2 = 0$

And $a_3 = 2a_2 - a_1 = 2*0 - 1 = -1$

So $a_4 = ????$

Comment: so a4 = 2a3 - a2 = 2 ∗ (-1) - 0 = -1?

Comment: @user9455658 You finally understood.

Comment: Except $2*(-1) - 0 \ne -1$.  Is the problem you have that you have difficulty multiplying and adding negative numbers?